# odometry message from Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, base-odometry, linear-velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to create and publish odometry data for a differential drive robot from an Arduino Due board with the data coming from wheel encoders and a gyro sensor attached to the board.

my intention is to create and publish the Odom messages from the Arduino Due itself, since it has a fairly powerful Microcontroller. (Is it a good practice?)

I have a few question though to clarify & make sure about a few things for myself. I check out the [publishing odometry tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) and i notice that there is a `odom.twist.twist.linear.y = vy` field, do I have to hard code this to `0.0` for a differential drive robot?

Is it alright if I just convert the gyro’s readings (which is in Degree Per Second) to Radian/sec and pass it straight as `vth` to `odom.twist.twist.angular.z = vth`?

In the Arduino it seems like that i can not use the odom_quat as in the tutorial to convert my heading to quats.
Instead should I add `odom_trans.transform.rotation.z` and `odom_trans.transform.rotation.w` to the message manually and calculate the value?

At what rate is the best practice to calculate and publish odometry for a Turtlebot class diff drive robot?

if you have any heads up or pointers regarding to what i'm trying to do I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241118/odometry-message-from-arduino/) by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can publish on /odom directly from the Due, and it should work fine. One possibility is to use the `rosserial` package. I've done this from an Arduino Leonardo. (However, I've dropped `rosserial` on the smaller Arduinos because of the memory usage of `rosserial`. You shouldn't have any problems on a Due.)

You should publish the odometry as `nav_msgs/Odometry`. Normally, you want to publish in the `base_link` frame, which often has its origin midway between the two wheels. By convention, `x` is straight ahead, and `z` is up. Therefore, since we assume there is no side-slip, you'll have the velocities in `twist.linear.x` and `twist.angular.z`. The pose will be in `pose`, including a quaternion for orientation. All other velocity values will be zero.

You should publish odometry at a rate equal to or higher than your planning loop rate. Also take your other sensors into account: you want up-to-date odometry when publishing a point cloud, for example. Depending on your setup, anything from 10-100 Hz might be best. Keep in mind the bandwidth required by `rosserial`, too. By default it's only 57600 baud, and messages are not tiny.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-04**:
Another option is to just deal with encoder tick rates on the Arduino and convert between ticks and /cmd_vel and /odom in a node on the host side. The `ros_arduino_bridge` package is set up this way, for example.

**Comment by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on 2016-08-04**:
Hi Mark, I am currently using the `rosserial` package ofc. I didnt get the part where you wrote i should publish odom as `geometry_msgs/Twist`. Do you happen to have any sample codes of the Arduino project you done? thanks for the reply!

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-04**:
I don't have any C++ code that does it. Instead, I usually publish encoder ticks from the Arduino and then convert to a `Twist` in Python on the host. For example, see this code in the `differential_drive package`: https://github.com/jfstepha/differential-drive/blob/master/scripts/diff_tf.py

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-04**:
Also see [this explanation of differential drive kinematics](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node659.html). And I've edited my answer above, which was wrong: you publish `nav_msgs/Odometry`, of course.

**Comment by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on 2016-08-04**:
Since the Arduino's loop function (which controls wheels and sensor readings too) loops at a constant low delay, my dt will always be the same amount & messages could overwhelm the link. I think the good practice is to just calc the velocities and send them to the host machine to manage Odom. right?

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-05**:
That's the way I've done it, but YMMV. As far as the send rate, you'll need to control the motors only periodically on the Arduino, either using `delay()` at the bottom of the `loop()` code, or checking the elapsed time during the loop to see if it's time to control the motors and publish.

**Comment by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on 2016-08-08**:
Thank you @Mark Rose. I'll wait a little longer to see if anyone else wants to chip in with ideas and then mark your answer as correct.

**Comment by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on 2016-08-08**:
@Mark Rose, another tiny confirmation; Theta must be presented in Radians in all odom calculations, is that correct? for example where it says: `delta_x = (vx * cos(th) - vy * sin(th)) * dt` "th" should be in rad and "vy = 0" for a differential drive robot...?

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-09**:
Yes, angles are always in radians. A couple of good things to read are [REP 103 - Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) and [REP 105 - Coordinate Frames for Mobile Platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html). And yes, `vy` will be zero.

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2016-12-29**:
So basically, I dont need to calculate dt on the Arduino explicitly beacause of the constant frequency of the loop? @Mark Rose and @ stevej_80 please kindly correct me.